# Emacs dired, what controls the color of the title line of a directory

Tags: emacs, dired

[image]
As the picture shown in attachment, what is the variable, if any, that controls the color of the title line of the directory? I'm trying to change the darkgreen to grey.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The screenshot you show indicates that you are using library [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus).

The face in question is `diredp-dir-heading`.

You can tell what the face is yourself, by asking Emacs. Put the cursor on the text that has that face and hit `C-u C-x =`, and you will see info about the character at point and its highlighting, i.e., including its face(s).

In this case, you see this:

```
There are text properties here:
  face                 diredp-dir-heading
  fontified            t
```

with `diredp-dir-heading` as a link.  And if you click that link then you see a description of its attributes and a link `customize this face`.  If you click that link then you are taken to a Customize buffer for customizing the face.  There, you can change its appearance and save your changes.

Note that there is no **variable** that controls the appearance here, that is, not a variable in the Emacs (Lisp) sense.  Instead, there is a **face** that controls it.  And just as you can set a variable value so can you set the attributes (appearance) of a face.

Comment: If it answers the question, you are welcome to accept the answer. People looking for only unanswered questions will then be less likely to check this one.